# Нормальзация строки юникода с убиранием умляутов и прочих диакритиков

Tags: c#, инспекция-кода, unicode, .net-5

Есть задача - организовать поиск по тексту слов в разных языках. При этом в словах могут встречаться диакритики и прочие прелести всех возможных юникодов.

К примеру, есть названия 2 кораблей - немецкий `Großer Kurfürst` и польский `Błyskawica`. Я хочу написав `grosser` или `blyska` найти эти названия в тексте. Для того, чтобы это вообще было возможно, используется функция нормализации текста, которая применяется и к поисковой строке, и к самому тексту. О ней и пройдет дальше речь.

Есть рабочее, проверенное, пуленепробиваемое решение.

```cs
public static string NormalizeUnicode(string text)
{
    string stFormD = text.ToLower()
        .Replace('\u00A0', ' ') // неразрывный пробел
        .Replace("ß", "ss")
        .Replace('ł', 'l')
        .Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(stFormD.Length);
    foreach (char c in stFormD) 
        if (CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(c) != UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark) 
            sb.Append(c);
    return sb.ToString().Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormC);
}
```

Которое на выходе выдаст `grosser kurfurst` и `blyskawica` соответственно. Проблема лишь в том, что оно хоть работает и с приемлемой скоростью, но хотелось бы быстрее.

С тех пор как это решение было взято в использование (найдено на просторах англоязычного интернета), прошло уже много времени, за которое появился .NET 5 с его спанами и прочими прелестями C# 8-9. И я попробовал оптимизировать.

**Код для инспекции**

```cs
public static string NormalizeUnicodeNew(string text)
{
    ReadOnlySpan<char> stFormD = text.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(stFormD.Length);
    foreach (char c in stFormD)
    {
        switch (CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(c))
        {
            case UnicodeCategory.UppercaseLetter:
                sb.Append(char.ToLower(c));
                break;
            case not UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark:
                if (c == 'ß')
                    sb.Append("ss");
                else
                    sb.Append(c switch
                    {
                        '\u00A0' => ' ',
                        'ł' => 'l',
                        _ => c
                    });
                break;
        }
    }
    return sb.ToString().Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormC);
}
```

Тестовый код

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    string s = "Großer Kurfürst, Błyskawica";
    string text = string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(s, 1000000));
    Console.WriteLine(s);
    Console.WriteLine(NormalizeUnicode(s));

    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    string n = NormalizeUnicode(text);
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

    sw.Restart();
    string m = NormalizeUnicodeNew(text);
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

    Console.WriteLine(m == n);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Вывод в консоль на релизном билде

```
Großer Kurfürst, Błyskawica
grosser kurfurst, blyskawica
780
562
True
```

Прирост по скорости действительно ощутимый ~15%, и это уже победа. Время замеряю грубо, бенчмарки пока не запускал.

Хочу узнать ваше мнение и советы, где еще можно подкрутить. Была идея использовать `string.Create`, но она разбилась о то, что я не знаю, какой длины будет выходная после фильтрации строка.

Comment: По-моему, в конце обоих методов нет необходимости приводить строку в `FormC`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov есть, потому что есть еще корейские закорючки, которые декомпозируются в несколько символов в `FormD`, и их надо собирать обратно.

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что Вы заменяете только приведённые в коде знаки? Или их много и Вы их не привели ради экономии места?

Comment: @XelaNamed только эти, в вопросе приведен полный код метода.

Comment: @AK код работающий, вопрос соответствует описанным требованиям в метке. Или в эту метку должны быть вопросы только типа "я тут понакодил, посмотрите пожалуйста"? Метку можно убрать, я не настаиваю, но есть ли в этом смысл?

Comment: Вот не знаю. Посмотрел текущее описание метки, там есть про "производительность" -- так что это вопрос не к вам, а на мету. Просто в текущей практике не встречалось мне подобного рода вопросов. Оставьте так.

Comment: Для начала неплохо бы запустить профайлер и посмотреть, на каких участках кода больше всего тратится времени на выполнение и что является боттлнеком.

Comment: Будь это питон, я бы попробовал ещё кэширование какое прикрутить. Если в задаче можно отдельными словами текст обрабатывать. Я бы побил текст на слова, к обработке слов приделал кэширование (если слово уже обрабатывалось - брать результат из кэша). На больших однородных текстах может и дало бы прирост (а может и нет - надо проверять, смотря что там тормозит).

Comment: @CrazyElf непротухающий кеш - хорошая мысль.С тайским языком только проблема была бы. Там пробелами предложения разбиваются, а слова пишутся все слитно. Решение для своей задачи пока и так имеет хорошие характеристики, но приятно знать, что есть ещё куда двигаться.

Comment: @aepot Ну, кстати, да, в данном случае кэш не устаревает, можно со временем вообще все возможные слова "перевести" и всё будет браться из кэша готовое. Если кэш сильно разбухнет - оставлять в нём только сильно повторяющиеся слова. Ну это надо статистику попадания в кэш и в целом профайлинг смотреть в общем.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Остановился на таком решении.

```cs
public static string NormalizeUnicodeNew(string text)
{
    ReadOnlySpan<char> stFormD = text.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD);
    int i = 0;
    Span<char> span = new char[stFormD.Length * 2];
    foreach (char c in stFormD)
    {
        UnicodeCategory category = CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(c);
        if (category == UnicodeCategory.UppercaseLetter)
            span[i++] = char.ToLower(c);
        else if (category != UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark)
            span[i++] = c switch
            {
                'ß' => span[i++] = 's',
                '\u00A0' => ' ',
                'ł' => 'l',
                _ => c
            };
    }
    return new string(span[..i]).Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormC);
}
```

`StringBuilder` конечно быстрый, но `Span` оказался быстрее. Прирост производительности еще ~20%, чем оптимизированное решение из вопроса.

В процессе оптимизации выяснил

- Ковариантный `c switch { }` медленный, это когда например
  `sb.Append(c switch { 'a' => 'b', 'c' => "de" })`.
- `if else if` - быстрее, чем `switch (...) { }` с двумя ветками.
- `string.Concat(IEnumerable<char>)` сильно медленнее, чем `new string(IEnumerable<char>.ToArray())`, но это не пригодилось. :)